# In variational inference on von Mises clusters, how to find a bound for the log-Bessel function?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning, variational-bayes

This [paper](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/gopal14.pdf) on von Mises clustering uses an upper bound on the modified log-Bessel function that I struggle to replicate. Taking results from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4814v2.pdf), the authors state:

$$u\frac{I'_\nu(u)}{I_\nu(u)} \le \sqrt{u^2 + v^2} $$ $$  \frac{I'_\nu(u)}{I_\nu(u)} \le \frac{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}{u} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{v^2}{u^2}} \tag{1}$$

The paper has a few apparent typos, but it seems to intend this bound derived by "integrating over $u > 0$," which I *think* means the indefinite integral:

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2 + \nu^2}}{u} du = \sqrt{u^2 + \nu^2} - \nu \log(\nu (\sqrt{u^2 + \nu^2} + \nu)) + \nu \log(u) + c \tag{2}$$

The definite integral over $u >0 $ doesn't converge, but the proposed bound seems to resemble the indefinite integral of the right-hand side, less a constant $c$. Though, when I plot the indefinite integral for $c=0$, against the modified log-Bessel, the bound only holds through a few orders of $\nu$. (Image and code below.)

How might one approach integrating $(1)$ to find a bound that holds? I thought of integrating over $(a,x)$ and setting $a$ such that $I_\nu
(a) = 1$. Then,
$$\int_a^x\frac{I'_\nu(u)}{I_\nu(u)}du = \log I_\nu(u)\rvert_a^x \le \int_a^x\frac{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}{u} du$$

$$\log I_\nu(x) - \log I_\nu(a) \le \sqrt{u^2 + \nu^2} - \nu \log(\nu (\sqrt{u^2 + \nu^2} + \nu)) + \nu \log(u)\rvert_a^x$$

Which given that $\log I_\nu(a) = 0$ and some right-hand finagling gives:

$$\log I_\nu(x) \le \sqrt{x^2 + \nu^2} - \sqrt{a^2 + \nu^2} - \nu \log \frac{a(\sqrt{x^2 - \nu^2} + \nu)}{x(\sqrt{a^2 - \nu^2} + \nu)}\tag{3}$$

This bound passes a quick visual check for $\nu > \frac{1}{2}$, and for $\nu = \frac{1}{2}$ seems to be equal within machine precision. Is there a way to derive the result using the indefinite integral as seemingly employed in the paper, or is my bound using the definite integral correct?

[image]

[image]

```
"""
Created on Tue Jan 10 09:02:19 2017

@author: seaneaster
"""

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from scipy.special import iv

def upper_bound(u,v):
    sum_squares = np.power(u,2) + np.power(v,2)
    root = np.sqrt(sum_squares)
    rv = root - v * np.log(v * root + np.power(v,2)) + v * np.log(u)
    return rv

def new_upper_bound(u,v):
    a = find_intersection(lambda x: iv(v, x), lambda x: 1, np.sqrt(v))
    u_sum_squares = np.power(u,2) + np.power(v,2)
    a_sum_squares = np.power(a,2) + np.power(v,2)
    u_term_root, a_term_root = np.sqrt(u_sum_squares), np.sqrt(a_sum_squares)
    rv = u_term_root - a_term_root - v * np.log(np.divide(a * u_term_root + v, u * a_term_root + v))
    return rv, a

def find_intersection(f1, f2, x0):
    return fsolve(lambda x: f1(x) - f2(x), x0)

def plot_all(u):

    f = plt.figure()

    for i in range(9):
        v = 0.5 * (i+1)
        plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.tick_params(
            which='both',      
            bottom='off',      
            top='off',
            left='off',
            labelleft='off',
            labelbottom='off')
        log_I = np.log(iv(v, u))
        bd = upper_bound(u,v)
        plt.plot(u, log_I, 'b', u, bd, 'g')
        print( (log_I <= bd).sum() )
    f.suptitle('Bound as in (1) w/ c = 0')

def plot_new(u):

    f = plt.figure()

    for i in range(9):
        v = 0.5 * (i+1)
        plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.tick_params(
            which='both',      
            bottom='off',      
            top='off',
            left='off',
            labelleft='off',
            labelbottom='off')
        log_I = np.log(iv(v, u))
        bd, a = new_upper_bound(u,v)
        plt.plot(u, log_I, 'b', u, bd, 'g')
        in_range_idx = u <= a
        in_range = log_I[in_range_idx]
        perc = (in_range <= bd[in_range_idx]).sum() / len(in_range)
        print( perc)

    f.suptitle('Bound as in (3)')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    u = np.linspace(0,5,num=1000)[1:]

    plot_all(u)
    plot_new(u)
```

Comment: Could you indicate what bounds you are using on your integral?  As it is written, the integral itself is a function only of $v$.

Comment: @whuber After reading your comment, I realized that the bounds are...*integral*—sorry, couldn't be helped—to my question: I'd like to understand how one can properly integrate the inequality to derive a proper bound on $\log I$. I played a bit more with the equations and updated the question. Is the thrust clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that one can apply definite integral [inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities) to find piecewise bounds for $\log I_\nu(x)$. The [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4814v2.pdf) from which the inequalities are taken includes both lower and upper bounds:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu+1}u^2 + \nu^2} \lt u \frac{I'_\nu(u)}{I_\nu(u)} \lt \sqrt{u^2 + \nu^2} 
$$

Divide all three terms by $u$; call the the left-most side of the resulting inequality $f_\nu(u)$ and the right-most $g_\nu(u)$, $F$ and $G$ their respective anti-derivatives w.r.t. $u$. 
For any $(a, b)$:

$$
F_\nu(b) - F_\nu(a) \lt \log I_\nu(b) - \log I_\nu(a) \lt G_\nu(b) - G_\nu(a)
$$

Setting $a$ such that $I_\nu(a) = 1$ and integrating over $(x,a)$ and $(a,x)$ gives:

$$
\begin{align}
F_\nu(a) - F_\nu(x) \lt - \log I_\nu(x) \Rightarrow \log I_\nu(x) \lt F_\nu(x) - F_\nu(a) && \text{for } x \lt a
\\
\log I_\nu(x) \lt G_\nu(x) - G_\nu(a) && \text{for }  x \gt a
\end{align}
$$

These pass a manual check up to $\nu = 50$ (below). That code simply evaluates the integral, but the bounds can be expressed like so:

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{\nu (x^2 + \nu^2 + \nu)}{\nu+1}} - 
\sqrt{\frac{\nu (a^2 + \nu^2 + \nu)}{\nu+1}} - 
\nu\log \frac{a\big(\sqrt{(x^2+\nu^2 + \nu)} + \sqrt{\nu(\nu+1)} \big)}{x\big(\sqrt{(a^2+\nu^2 + \nu)} + \sqrt{\nu(\nu+1)}\big)}  && \text{for } x \gt a
\\
\sqrt{x^2 + \nu^2} - \sqrt{a^2 + \nu^2} - \nu \log \frac{a(\sqrt{x^2 - \nu^2} + \nu)}{x(\sqrt{a^2 - \nu^2} + \nu)}  && \text{for } x \lt a
\end{align}
$$

Deriving these from [$F_\nu$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(v+%2F+(v%2B+1)+%2B+v%5E2+%2F+u%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)+du) and [$G_\nu$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1+%2B+v%5E2+%2F+u%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)+du) is left to the interested reader. (I know you're out there, somewhere.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 17 14:08:24 2017

@author: seaneaster
"""

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from scipy.special import iv
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def find_intersection(f1, f2, x0):
    return fsolve(lambda x: f1(x) - f2(x), x0, maxfev = 10000)

def lta_def_integral_eval(u, v, c = 0):
    first_term = np.sqrt(v / (v + 1) * (np.power(u, 2) + np.power(v, 2) + v))
    second_term = - v * np.log(v + np.power(v, 2) + np.sqrt(v * (v + 1) * (np.power(u, 2) + np.power(v, 2) + v)))
    third_term = v * np.log(u)
    return first_term + second_term + third_term + c

def gta_def_integral_eval(u, v, c = 0):
    sum_squares = np.power(u, 2) + np.power(v, 2)
    root_sum_squares = np.sqrt(sum_squares)
    return root_sum_squares - v * np.log(v * (root_sum_squares + v)) + v * np.log(u)

def bound_lta(u, v, a):
    return lta_def_integral_eval(u, v) - lta_def_integral_eval(a, v)

def bound_gta(u, v, a):
    return gta_def_integral_eval(u, v) - gta_def_integral_eval(a, v)

def find_a(v, guess = None):
    if guess == None:
        guess = np.power(v, 1.5)
    return find_intersection(lambda x: iv(v, x), lambda x: 1, guess)

def plot_all(u):

    f = plt.figure()

    for i in range(9):
        v = 0.5 * (i+1)
        a = find_a(v)
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.tick_params(
            which='both',      
            bottom='off',      
            top='off',
            left='off',
            labelleft='off',
            labelbottom='off')
        log_I = np.log(iv(v, u))
        lta_bd = bound_lta(u, v, a)
        gta_bd = bound_gta(u, v, a)
        bd = np.where(u < a, lta_bd, gta_bd)
        plt.plot(u, log_I, 'b', u, bd, 'g')
        y1, y2 = ax.get_ylim()
        plt.vlines(a, y1, y2)
        print("v: ", v, "a value: ", a, " perc: ", (log_I <= bd).sum() )
    f.suptitle('Piecewise bound')

def test_bds():
    max_order = 50
    num = 1000
    fmt_str = "Break on v = {}, count under bound (of 1000): {}, a = {}"
    breakdown_order = None
    for v in [(_ + 0.5) for _ in range(max_order + 1)]:
        a = find_a(v)
        u = np.linspace(0, a + 5, num = num + 1)[1:]
        log_I = np.log(iv(v, u))
        lta_bd = bound_lta(u, v, a)
        gta_bd = bound_gta(u, v, a)
        bd = np.where(u < a, lta_bd, gta_bd)
        count_lower = (log_I < bd).sum()
        if count_lower < num:
            print(fmt_str.format(v, count_lower, a))
    if breakdown_order == None:
        print("No break through order {}".format(max_order))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    u = np.linspace(0, 10,num=1001)[1:]
    test_bds()
```